# R Matrix Row.names adding a number at the end of every repeated string

Tags: r

im uing the row names function to track the production capacity of power producing facilities based on the fuel they use. when i go to create a barplot of the data, instead of creating a nice bar plot of the 6 types of fuel im interested in, i instead get a plot that looks like this
[bad bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIJd2.png)

when i reviewed my matrix, i found that my data looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNWHw.png)

does anyone know how i can effectively group this dataset to fix my barplot?

code used

```
install.packages('ggplot2', 'tidyverse')
install.packages('tidyverse')
library('tidyverse')
Power_Facilities<- read.csv('powerplants (global) - global_power_plants.csv')
drop<-c("secondary.fuel", "other_fuel2", "other_fuel3", "geolocation_source")
PF<-Power_Facilities[,!(names(Power_Facilities) %in% drop)]
PF<-subset(PF,PF$capacity.in.MW>2000)
PF$generated <-(ifelse(is.na (PF$generation_gwh_2021), paste(PF$estimated_generation_gwh_2021), PF$generation_gwh_2021))
PF$generated <-as.numeric(PF$generated)
#PF<- PF [!((PF$generated == "NA") | PF$generated==""), ]
#PF<- PF [!((PF$generated >1)),]
#PF<- PF [!((PF$capacity.in.MW<20)), ]



head(sort(PF$capacity.in.MW, decreasing = TRUE))
tail(sort(PF$capacity.in.MW, decreasing = TRUE))
head(sort(PF$generated, decreasing = TRUE))
tail(sort(PF$generated, decreasing = TRUE))
pf2<-PF%>%group_by(primary_fuel)summarize

barplot((PF2$capacity.in.MW), names.arg =pf2$primary_fuel)
barplot(t(power_matrix), beside = T, las=2, legend.text =T, col = c("blue", "grey"), ylim=c(0, 1000000))

summary(power_matrix)
```

````
structure(list(country.code = c("AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AZE", "BHR", 
"BLR", "BEL", "BEL", "BRA", "BRA"), country_long = c("Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Belarus", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Brazil"), name.of.powerplant = c("Bayswater", 
"Liddell", "Loy Yang A", "Azerbaijan TPP", "Alba Power Station", 
"Lukoml Thermal Power Plant Belarus", "DOEL 4", "TIHANGE 3", 
"Belo Monte", "Ilha Solteira"), capacity.in.MW = c(2640, 2200, 
2180, 2400, 2204, 2460, 2910, 2053.8, 3327.45544, 3444), latitude = c(-32.3953, 
-32.3713, -38.2536, 40.78, 26.0945, 54.6803, 51.3254, 50.5342, 
-3.1264, -20.3822), longitude = c(150.9491, 150.9776, 146.5746, 
46.9901, 50.6008, 29.1341, 4.2597, 5.2751, -51.775, -51.3636), 
    primary_fuel = c("Coal", "Coal", "Coal", "Oil", "Gas", "Gas", 
    "Nuclear", "Nuclear", "Hydro", "Hydro"), start.date = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1985, 1985, 2016, 1973), owner.of.plant = c("Macquarie Generation", 
    "Macquarie Generation", "GEAC Great Energy Alliance Corporation", 
    "AzerEnerji", "Aluminum Bahrain", "", "", "", "", ""), generation_gwh_2021 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), estimated_generation_gwh_2021 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17396.84, 6318.07), generated = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17396.84, 6318.07)), row.names = c(356L, 
565L, 573L, 927L, 942L, 1017L, 1044L, 1083L, 1386L, 2164L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: Row names must be unique. I'd suggest using a `data.frame` not a `matrix` and putting the labels you want in a column.

Comment: @GregorThomas, thanks, running as a dataframe is better, do you know how i can group the names though that?

Comment: Add a few rows (like 5-10 rows) of sample data in a copy/pasteable format and it will be much easier to help. If your data is called `your_data`, then you can use the `dput()` command to make a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows like this: `dput(your_data[1:10, ])`.

Comment: @GregorThomas added into the main body

Answer (score 0):

I'd pivot your data to long format and use `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
PF2_long = PF2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(generated, capacity.in.MW), names_to = "measure") 
ggplot(PF2_long, aes(x = primary_fuel, y = value, fill = measure)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey60")) +
  labs(
    x = "Primary fuel",
    y = "MW",
    fill = ""
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]